# jquery hide and show on different places

Tags: jquery, html

I use jquery to show text when a button is clicked. 
I want on the same page on another spot with another button showing a different text. 
My solution now is to create multiple scripts one for each div like this

```
<a class="pure-button pure-button-primary" type='button' id='hideshow1' value='hide/show1' >Show me1 ! </a>
<div id='content1' style="display:none">  hide and show 1 </div>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#hideshow1').on('click', function(event) {        
             jQuery('#content1').toggle('hide');
        });
    });
</script>
```

And a copy of this all but then with 'hideshow2' and 'content2'

Now i need even a third hideshow3  but i can't figure out how to make this smarter with just one script.

Comment: Is the element with content always going to be next to the element you click? If so you can do `jQuery('.pure-button').on('click', function() { jQuery(this).next().toggle('hide'); })`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead work with class names. That will not give you pain of writing same thing over and over again:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.hideshow').on('click', function(event) {
    jQuery(this).next('.content').toggle('hide');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="pure-button pure-button-primary hideshow" type='button' value='hide/show1'>Show me1 ! </a>
<div class='content' style="display:none">hide and show 1</div><br>
<a class="pure-button pure-button-primary hideshow" type='button' value='hide/show1'>Show me2 ! </a>
<div class='content' style="display:none">hide and show 2</div><br>
<a class="pure-button pure-button-primary hideshow" type='button' value='hide/show1'>Show me3 ! </a>
<div class='content' style="display:none">hide and show 3</div>
```

Comment: It's highly unlikely they will be next to each other, surely the question has it this way to show the html, not the structure?

Comment: You are right but i just wanted to answer based on the markup with least changes.

Answer (score 1):

**in link type attribute and value its bad...**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('a[id^="hideshow"]').on('click', function(event) {        
             $(this).next().toggle('hide');
        });
    });
```

```css
a{ display: block; cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="pure-button pure-button-primary" id='hideshow1'>Show me1 ! </a>
<div id='content1' style="display:none">  hide and show 1 </div>

<a class="pure-button pure-button-primary" id='hideshow2'>Show me2 ! </a>
<div id='content2' style="display:none">  hide and show 2 </div>

<a class="pure-button pure-button-primary" id='hideshow3'>Show me3 ! </a>
<div id='content3' style="display:none">  hide and show 3 </div>
```

Comment: It's highly unlikely they will be next to each other, surely the question has it this way to show the html, not the structure?

Comment: this solution for structure of  author

Comment: I got 6 answers, can vote just one.  But this one looks great for me and what i looked for. Thank you for your effort

Answer (score 0):

> use jquery to show text when a button is clicked

You can link them with `data-` attributes.  This way it doesn't matter if the elements are near each other and can be moved around in future without needing to rewrite the script.

```
<a class='hideshow' data-hideshow="1">Show me 1!</a>
<a class='hideshow' data-hideshow="2">Show me 2!</a>

<div class='content' data-hideshow="1" style="display:none">hide and show 1 </div>
<div class='content' data-hideshow="2" style="display:none">hide and show 2 </div>
```

Then your script works on classes and the attributes:

```
$(".hideshow").click(function() {
    var hideshow = $(this).data("hideshow");

    // Optional hide all other .content (not clear if this is required or not)
    $(".content").hide();

    // Show the relevant .content
    $(".content[data-hideshow=" + hideshow + "]").show();
});
```

The .hide()/.show() calls can be made more efficient by combining with .not() and other calls, but this shows the concept.

Comment: This doesn't do a `toggle` like OP is doing. You can't hide for example `hide and show 1` by clicking on the first link.

Comment: @putvande You are correct, it doesn't match OPs original code - however, it does match OPs question - I went with the text in the question "*use jquery to show text when a button is clicked.*" and caption of the link "*show me 1*" both of which are "show", not toggle.

Answer (score 0):

i think you want to have a structure like button div button div button div . so use this

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/kv2nqhqv/2/)**

JQ

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(".pure-button").on('click', function(event) {        
    var show = $(this).next("div")
         $(show).toggle('hide');
    });
 });
```

HTML :

```
<a class="pure-button pure-button-primary" type='button' id='hideshow1' value='hide/show1' >Show me1 ! </a>
<div id='content1' style="display:none">  hide and show 1 </div>
<a class="pure-button pure-button-primary" type='button' id='hideshow2' value='hide/show2' >Show me2 ! </a>
<div id='content2' style="display:none">  hide and show 2 </div>
<a class="pure-button pure-button-primary" type='button' id='hideshow3' value='hide/show3' >Show me3 ! </a>
<div id='content3' style="display:none">  hide and show 3 </div>
<a class="pure-button pure-button-primary" type='button' id='hideshow4' value='hide/show4' >Show me4 ! </a>
<div id='content4' style="display:none">  hide and show 4 </div>
```

**OR** if your divs are not directly after the buttons, you could use `data-target` like so : [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/kv2nqhqv/3/)

HTML :

```
<a class="pure-button pure-button-primary" type='button' id='hideshow1' data-target="#content1" value='hide/show1' >Show me1 ! </a>
<a class="pure-button pure-button-primary" type='button' id='hideshow2' data-target="#content2" value='hide/show2' >Show me2 ! </a>
<a class="pure-button pure-button-primary" type='button' id='hideshow3' data-target="#content3" value='hide/show3' >Show me3 ! </a>
<a class="pure-button pure-button-primary" type='button' id='hideshow4' data-target="#content4" value='hide/show4' >Show me4 ! </a>

<div id='content1' style="display:none">  hide and show 1 </div>
<div id='content2' style="display:none">  hide and show 2 </div>
<div id='content3' style="display:none">  hide and show 3 </div>
<div id='content4' style="display:none">  hide and show 4 </div>
```

JQ :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".pure-button").click(function() {        
    var show = $(this).data("target")
         $(show).toggle('hide');
    });
});
```

Comment: Why the `.each`? `jQuery('.pure-button').on('click'...` would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Why add classes to select elements? It's much more simple to use the jQuery selectors in the proper way.

A different approach, considering the "#contentx" element  can be not consecutive is:

```js
$(function () {
  // get all elements with the id starting with hideshow
  $('[id^="hideshow"]').on('click', function(event) {
    // find all content elements ending with the same
    // substring of the clicked element
    $('#content' + this.id.substr(8)).toggle('hide');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<a class="pure-button pure-button-primary" type='button' id='hideshow1' value='hide/show1' >Show me1 ! </a>
<div id='content1' style="display:none">  hide and show 1 </div>

<a class="pure-button pure-button-primary" type='button' id='hideshow2' value='hide/show1' >Show me1 ! </a>
<div id='content2' style="display:none">  hide and show 1 </div>

<a class="pure-button pure-button-primary" type='button' id='hideshow3' value='hide/show1' >Show me1 ! </a>
<div id='content3' style="display:none">  hide and show 1 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.pure-button').on('click', function(event) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    id = id.substring(8);
    $('#content' + id).toggle('hide');
  });
});
```

I think that code will help you, if the clicked button and display box have same numeric digit